# Getting a KeyValuePair<> directly from a Dictionary<>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, dictionary

I have `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<A, B> dict` where A and B are classes, and an instance `A a` (where `dict.ContainsKey(a)` is true).

Is it possible to get the KeyValuePair containing `a` directly from the Dictionary?
Or do I need to create a new KeyValuePair: `new KeyValuePair<A, B>(a, dict[a])`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to create a new `KeyValuePair`<sup>1</sup> - but bear in mind that KVP is a value type (a struct) anyway, so it's not like you're introducing a new inefficiency by doing this. Any method returning a KVP would be creating a copy anyway - you're just creating the instance directly.

You could always add an extension method to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` if you wanted:

```
public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> GetEntry<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
     TKey key)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, dictionary[key]);
}
```

As noted in comments, it's entirely possible that the key which is stored in the dictionary is not the *same* as the one provided, just semantically equal - by some semantics which could be customized by an `IEqualityComparer` (as with a case-insensitive dictionary, for example.) In that case, the code above would not return the actual entry in the dictionary, but an entry with the key you provided to look up. Unfortunately there's no efficient way of finding the original key - you'd have to iterate over the dictionary :(

---

<sup>1</sup> I was aware that you could iterate over the dictionary entries and find the appropriate entry that way, but I can see no reason why you'd ever want to do so when you've got a perfectly good indexer which is O(1) instead of O(N).

Comment: My line of thinking was: "It seems I can't get a reference to the actual KeyValuePair object within the dictionary. I wonder why not?". That KeyValuePair is a value type clearly answers that.

Thanks Jon

Comment: Unfortunately, the above only works if the key parameter and the key stored in the dictionary are semantically equal.  If one has a `Dictionary<string,string>` called `dic` constructed with `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` that contains {"Jon","Skeet"}, then `dic.GetEntry("JON")` would return {"JON","Skeet"}.  The only way I know to make a dictionary return the key on a lookup is to have the key be part of the value.  Seems silly, but I know of no alternative.

Comment: @eglasius: I really wish Sun and Microsoft had recognized that in many cases it's useful to have the exact key that is stored in a dictionary or set.  The lack of such ability is especially detrimental to Java's `WeakHashMap` [I can see stronger usage cases for a `WeakIdentityHashMap`, or a `WeakReflexiveSet` [that maps keys to themselves] than for a non-identity-based `WeakHashSet` that can't readily read back stored key values.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Glad we agree about something. Referring back to your post, do you think it might be worth making mention of the point in my earlier comment? The fact that `Dictionary` accepts an `IEqalityComparer` implies that it is not at all implausible that the key being searched for might be significantly different from the one in the dictionary.

Comment: @supercat: Yup, will do.

Answer (score 20):

As `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, you could use linq:

```
var pair = _dictionary.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == myKey);
```

Comment: Well yes, you *could* do that... but it's staggeringly inefficient compared with just fetching the key. (It also assumes that == has been overloaded for the key type, and that the dictionary is using that comparison.) Why would you ever want to do that rather than creating a new KVP directly?

Comment: its wrong!!! very bad code avoid it!!! consider a dictionary of 9999999 items, u can go to your item directly and create this pair,
or go through lots of items and get it...
think about it..

Comment: Using Linq may not be necessarily bad, and does not mandates a itearion through all the elements. It may be using internal hastable to get the single KeyValuePair. If you are using a foreach to iterate, then thats bad coding I guess!

Comment: @Adarsha: No, `SingleOrDefault` is an extension method for `IEnumerable`, which means that it treats the `Dictionary` as an Enumerable (i.e. relies only on `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`), which is iterative by nature.

Comment: This is perfect when trying to compare same instances of KeyValuePairs without having to create a custom comparer, especially for under the hood work.

Comment: "it's staggeringly inefficient compared with just fetching the key" -- there is no way to fetch a key from a Dictionary other than by enumerating it.

Comment: " does not mandates a itearion through all the elements" -- Single[OrDefault] certainly does.
"It may be using internal hastable to get the single KeyValuePair" -- well of course Dictionary has an internal hash table, but that's irrelevant. A hash table doesn't work with an arbitrary comparison predicate.

Comment: This was useful to me as I needed to add all of a dictionaries values to a list of KeyValuePairs. as I still needed the keys in the list, but they could be duplicated. And I just went exampleList.AddRange(dictionary)  and it worked great.

Comment: This can give wrong results if dictionary has a custom comparer. Just ensure you use the right comparer for Equals check. See [johv's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28898283) answer for a proper implementation.

Answer (score 3):

We can't get to `"IPHone"` this way:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               {
                   { "IPHone", "TCP/IP honing tools" }
               };

Console.WriteLine(dict["iPhone"]); // "TCP/IP honing tools"
Console.WriteLine( ??? ); // "IPHone"
```

There's seems to be no O(1) solution with the current API, but looping through all entries works:

```
var keyValue = dict.First(p => dict.Comparer.Equals(p.Key, "iPhone"));

Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key); // "IPHone"
Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Value); // "TCP/IP honing tools"
```

Or as an extension for the lazy:

```
[Pure]
public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> GetEntry<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    var comparer = dictionary.Comparer;
    return dictionary.FirstOrDefault(p => comparer.Equals(p.Key, key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `myDict.AsEnumerable` does it...

Comment: Note: `AsEnumerable` is indeed one way to "loop through all the entries", but does not solve the original question, which is whether there is an API that will let you get at the exact key, *without* going through all the entries. [To which the answer is still "No".]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer probably is not going to be too helpful for some common scenarios. Keep in mind that the key is a class. So, in order to access the value object for that key, a key object must already exist. So, what if you have an older key object and the dictionary contains newer information in that key object (but still using the same key fields within that key object)? Or, another quite plausible scenario is what if only the fields used as the key are available and a temporary key object is then created that incorporates those key fields?

The accepted answer uses an extension method to return a `KeyValuePair` that contains the old key, not the actual key object within the dictionary. As such, it is not going to work for these common cases.

So, Supercat's idea of using a `KeyValuePair` for the value that includes the key is the only approach that will work in O(1) time. The drawback is that this approach is not only more complex, but it also requires an extra 8 bytes (for a 64-bit OS) for each entry in the dictionary, which is usually not a concern. Looks like Microsoft missed the boat on this one, because they really should provide a method that returns the key in a dictionary.

Here is an example of how to create a dictionary with a `KeyValuePair` as the value:

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<a, KeyValuePair<a, b>>();
```

Then to access it:

```
    var kvp = dict[key]; // key is of type a.
    a itemKey = kvp.key;
    b itemVal = kvp.value;
```

So, code like this will work if you have control over the dictionary definition. If you are using 3rd party software, or it is too much trouble to change, then you have to iterate over the entire collection - which is an O(n) operation.