# Retrieving values from Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have dictionary with keys containing a list of strings.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> keyValueListDict=new Dictionary <string,List<string>>();
List<string>valueList = new List<string>();
```

My `keyValueListDict` is filled with unique keys and valueLists.  For each dictionary entry, I need to output the key followed by the contents of the list (value).

Update: I think the problem is coming from entering the values
So i am retrieving an object from my db

```
foreach(object)
{
  key=object.key;
  foreach(string value in object.othercomponent)
  {
    list.add(value);
  }
  keyValueListDict.add(key,list);
  list.clear();
}
```

The count for the values in the list resets to 0 everytime I clear the list so I can fill it for the next object, but I can't figure out how to avoid this

Comment: You are just trying to make one giant `List<string>`?

Comment: No, for every key, I am outputtuing the key and the values in the list associated with that key, then I reset the string.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the end result you're looking for is, as a result you've got like 5 answers all doing something slightly different. Do you want a string that is a concatenation of each value or each key-value pair? Or you do you want a list with each value, or each key-value pair? Each solution is here it seems, but you should try to be a little more explicit next time.

Comment: I need to output the values for a specific key, sorry if I did not make myself clear earlier. So I already have the key, and I need to output the values for that specific key in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to create one output string of the dictionary's entry key followed by the combined values.

```
public string GetOutputString(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp)
{
    string separator = ", ";  //you can change this if needed (maybe a newline?)
    string outputString = kvp.Key + " " + String.Join(separator, kvp.Value);
    return outputString;
}
```

If you only had the key (and not the entire `KeyValuePair`), you could create a copy from your dictionary with something like (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619090/getting-a-keyvaluepair-directly-from-a-dictionary) about getting a `KeyValuePair` directly from a dictionary)

```
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(key, keyValueListDict[key]);
```

If you needed to output the entire dictionary, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var kvp in keyValueListDict)
{
    string output = GetOutputString(kvp);
    //print output, write to file etc.
}
```

[Working .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S99FhR)

Comment: This is going to output all the keys and values at the one time, I need to output the values for a specific key, sorry if I did not make myself clear earlier. So I already have the key, and I need to output the values for that specific key in a string.

Comment: But then if I use the body of that loop how will my outputString recognize what dictionary to get the values from?

Comment: I did the following:
Console.WriteLine(key + ":");
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> (Key,keyValueListDict[Key]);
string outputString = kvp.Key + " " + String.Join(" ", kvp.Value);

Console.WriteLine("Values:");
Console.WriteLine(combindedString);

Comment: But I'm just getting an empty string

Comment: I take that back, I am getting the key, but not the values

Comment: why are you making a new dictionary if you just need the string? just do `String value = String.Join( ",", keyValueListDict[key].ToArray());`

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD Um, in your test, `Console.WriteLine(combindedString)` but what is `combindedString`?  You called the other thing `outputString`.  Look at this [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S99FhR)

Comment: @rickkr It's not a dictionary, only a `KeyValuePair`.  And it is just to force it into the form the method accepts.  AKA laziness.

Comment: No sorry mistake in copying and pasting but yeah I had the same string. I think my problem is stemming from entering values into the dictionary, not outputing, I will explain in the next comment

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD wait on that comment.  If it's a separate problem, it might belong in a separate question.  Just make sure that it is a full question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, sorry that was directed to projekted's solution. but yeah I still misread as a new dictionary, either way I don't think you need to create it.

Comment: So i am retrieving an object from my db
foreach(object)
{
  key=object.key;
  foreach(string value in object.othercomponent)
  {
    list.add(value);
  }
  keyValueListDict.add(key,list);
  list.clear();
}
Whenever I am clearing the list so I can add the next list, the count in list goes to 0 in the dictionary, but I can't figure out how to avoid that.

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD please include the _separate problem as a new question_.  You have plenty of answers for this question (about printing stuff in your dictionary).  If any of them have solved _this problem_ you can upvote or accept them.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var valueList = keyValueListDict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic approach to iterate over a dictionary:

```
var keyValueListDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
    {"fookey", {"foo", "bar", "baz"}},
    {"barkey", {"bar", "baz", "foo"}},
    {"bazkey", {"baz", "foo", "bar"}}
};
foreach(var entry in keyValueListDict) {
    string key = entry.Key;
    List<string> values = entry.Value;
    //Console.WriteLine(key + " => " + values);
    //Console.WriteLine(key + " => [" + string.Join(", ", values) + "]");
}
```

Comment: Why not, this a simple demonstration on how to iterate a dict

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
 {
    var tmp = string.Empty;
    foreach (var value in dictionary[key])
    {
       tmp +=value """";
       System.Console.WriteLine(tmp );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I has this problem today, and I didn't like being forced to change my data structure, I really wanted to maintain the `List<string>`. This worked for me.

```
var reportTabGridItems = expectedReportTabsWithReportItems.Where(x => x.Key == reportTabName).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

I just wanted one row, therefore I tacked on the `FirstOrDefault()` to the end since the last select will bring back a list of `list<string>` and I just want one (or null if not found).

Hope this helps you.