# How to get original case key by case insensitive key in Dictionary<string, int>

Tags: c#, dictionary, case-insensitive

There is Dictionary:

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {{"abc1", 1}, {"abC2", 2}, {"abc3", 3}};
```

I can get a value:

```
var value = dictionary1["Abc2"];
```

If search key `"Abc2"` I need to get the original key `"abC2"` and value 2.

How to get original case key by case insensitive key?

Comment: write your case insensitive index for dictionary

Comment: I don't think dictionaries work like that. Try a different data structure.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, where to put original case sensitive key?

Comment: Try to store the original key together with the value in a structure like `Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>`. Thus you'd get the value together with the original key.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is an entirely reasonable thing to want to do, and there's no reason why `Dictionary` *couldn't* provide this functionality. It just doesn't :(

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619090/getting-a-keyvaluepair-directly-from-a-dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that, unfortunately. It would be entirely reasonable for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to expose a `bool TryGetEntry(TKey key, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry)` method, but it doesn't do so.

As stop-cran suggested in comments, the simplest approach is probably to make each *value* in your dictionary a pair with the same key as the key in the dictionary. So:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    // You'd normally write a helper method to avoid having to specify
    // the key twice, of course.
    {"abc1", new KeyValuePair<string, int>("abc1", 1)},
    {"abC2", new KeyValuePair<string, int>("abC2", 2)},
    {"abc3", new KeyValuePair<string, int>("abc3", 3)}
};
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("Abc2", out var entry))
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key); // abC2
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Value); // 2
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key not found"); // We don't get here in this example
}
```

If this is a field in a class, you could write helper methods to make it simpler. You could even write your own wrapper class around `Dictionary` to implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` but add an extra `TryGetEntry` method, so that the caller never needs to know what the "inner" dictionary looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code that utilizes LINQ to get dictionary key value pair even when case is not matching for key.

NOTE: This code can be used for dictionary of any size, but it's most appropriate for smaller size dictionaries since the LINQ is basically checking each key value pair one by one as opposed to directly going to the desired key value pair.

```
Dictionary<string,int> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    {"abc1",1},
    {"abC2",2},
    {"abc3",3}
    } ;

var value1 = dictionary1["ABC2"];//this gives 2, even though case of key does not macth

//use LINQ to achieve your requirement
var keyValuePair1 = dictionary1.SingleOrDefault (d => d.Key.Equals("Abc2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) );

var key1 = keyValuePair1.Key ;//gives us abC2
var value2 =keyValuePair1.Value;//gives us 2
```

Comment: But that turns an O(1) operation into an O(n) operation, making the use of a dictionary relatively pointless. It may be okay in very niche cases, but I'd generally assume that if a dictionary is being used, it's at least partly to avoid O(n) lookups.

Comment: That is correct since dictionary is supposed to be fast.  But how about if dictionary is small in size?

Comment: Then sure, it'll work - but I think that *at least* deserves to be included very prominently in an answer, as it goes against the usual expectations of using a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for that important info. I have added this as a note in my answer.

Comment: @Sunil, as pointed Daisy Shipton it is pointless for me. The whole procedure with this dictionary is web request and is already taking 1 hour which is too long. I need it as fast as possible for 100000 items in dictionary. But for short dictionaries it is definitely useful.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, then I would test out the scenarios rather than just go by theoretical conclusions. Try out both methods and see what is the difference. Even LINQ does optimization behind the scenes.

Comment: @Sunil, here is my report of benchmark. Original container was XML so I included it too. This is like in my production: cycle of 10000 with Dictionary of 15 items. This are the times spent:
HashTable - 47;
Dictionary - 229;
LINQ         - 437;
XML          - 470.
Of course HashTable is the fastest.

Comment: @ildar, those times are in milliseconds?   What method you used for LINQ? You have only 15 items in your dictionary. Try to have more items in dictionary like few thousands and get time per cycle for best comparison.

Comment: @Sunil, those times in milliseconds multiplied by 10 so for LINQ in millisecond it is 43.7 ms, for HashTable 4.7 ms and so on. For LINQ I've used exactly as you wrote.

Comment: @ildar, keep in mind that the accepted answer would take more memory when you are talking about your scenario with 1 million items in dictionary, since the value is not just an integer but a key value pair.

Comment: @ildar, So those are times for 10,000 trials? If yes, then time per search is very very low. And please don't disregard memory for 1 million items. It will be like memory for 2 such dictionaries and some more if you follow the accepted answer approach.

Comment: @Sunil, as I explained in my comment above the critical is only the time. So I am using for my particular project accepted answer. I like LINQ but not for time consuming procedures and I'll keep in mind your answer and my benchmark for future cases.

Comment: @ildar, this is not about my or the accepted answer, just trying to highlight different aspects of performance in real execution.